# What was the date when everyone first started getting the Enthusiast badge on SO?

Tags: discussion, activity-badges

Anyone remember when it was?

Comment: The data dump would be able to tell you that.

Comment: This leads to the follow-up: When the hell am I getting Fanatic?!

Comment: @Eric, I believe the first Fanatic badges will begin going out on or about September 3, 2009

Comment: And I'm going to be on vacation for the two weeks preceding that date. *sob*

Comment: I am gonna have to wait until winter to get my fanatic badge...Too many vacations this summer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well using the query:

```
select Date from badges where name = 'Enthusiast' and userid = 2598
```

(I don't actually know sql btw)

I found that my badge was awarded on `'1246043556'`, or `'GMT: Fri, 26 Jun 2009 19:12:36 GMT`'.

<s>Anyone know how to convert that to a pretty time stamp?</s>

Thanks to http://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

I believe [June 26](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/). Also, the initial announcement was on [May 26](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/server-fault-public-beta-launches/).